# Java - Array required but *** found and symbol not found

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on something but I got this problem that I cannot resolve...
There are 2 situations, but I need both of them at once...

```
1   @Test
2   public void newStackIsFull() {
3       BoundedStack targetStack = new BoundedStack(5);
4       targetStack[0] = new BoundedStack();
5       assertTrue(targetStack.isFull());
6   }
```

In this case, I get an error on line 4: `array required, but BoundedStack found`

If I alter the code to this:

```
1   @Test
2   public void newStackIsFull() {
3       BoundedStack[] targetStack = new BoundedStack[5];
4       targetStack[0] = new BoundedStack();
5       assertTrue(targetStack.isFull());
6   }
```

Here I got an error on line 5: `cannot find symbol .isFull()`

The problem is that I need BOTH situation at once. So I must be able to read from the array, put things in the array, ... and also use the methods from the BoundedStack class..

Comment: What library is BoundedStack a part of? I can't see it in the Java built-ins; is it something you wrote? If so, did you make docs? If not, could you tell us the name of the library it came from?

Comment: In the first case targetStack is an Object... so you can't say targetStack[0] because targetStack is NOT an array. In the second case targetStack is an array, so the array NOT has isFull method. Are you sure about what you are searching for?

Comment: targetStack[0].isFull() ??? i.e. are you just not referencing the item in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example has a compile-time error because you are trying to access the first element of an array, but `targetStack`is in fact a `BoundedStack` and not an array.

Your second example also has a compile-time error ; this time, you are trying to call the `isFull` method on an array (the `targetStack`variable), and this method does not exist for arrays.

You seem to confuse an array of an object and the object itself.

```
BoundedStack[] targetStack = new BoundedStack[5];
//targetStack is now an array of 5 BoundedStack and not a BoundedStack
//targetStack[0] is the first element of the array, beware that as of this moment, it is null because the array was not initialized
targetStack[0] = new BoundedStack(); //you create a new BoundedStack object
System.out.println(targetStack[0].isFull()); //we print if this first element is full or not.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extend array type in java : you can't. full stop.

However you can use an implementation of the `List` interface (an `ArrayList` here seems a good choice) that will store things with an index and you can retrieve things using the `get` method :

```
List<BoundedStack> list = new ArrayList<BoundedStack>();
list.add(new BoundedStack());
list.get(0);
list.isEmpty();
```

If you want to add methods to this class, then you can extend it.

Comment: I think the point is that they want to use array-like operations on a `BoundedStack` object, but don't know how. I don't think they want an array of BoundedStack objects.

Comment: Which will mean they want to somehow extend the array type, which is not possible in java.

Comment: But you're suggesting that they use a `List` of `BoundedStack`s -- what I'm saying is that I think OP wants to use `BoundedStack` in place of a list. It's perfectly possible to make an analogous object to Array without extending it directly.

Comment: It is correct that I try to use the BoundedStack instead of a list... The assignment says: define and implement a class BoundedStack (use an array to store the elements) ........ implement following methods: ......